# Помогите с запятой, пожалуйста

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите с запятой, не могу понять, по какой причине там не должно быть её.

> Эта встреча случилась в лесистой и пустынной стороне невдалеке от Москвы.

Почему нет запятой, ведь это уточнение?

Comment: На мой взгляд, если бы это уточнение стояло бы после слова "встреча", то обособление было бы необходимым

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта встреча случилась в лесистой и пустынной стороне **невдалеке** от Москвы.

Запятую можно поставить только при очень большом желании, и как авторскую. Если каждое такое "уточнение" выделять запятыми, текст превратится в спотыкач.